# Does iOS 4 make “Real Multitasking” available to 3rd party developers?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

Ever since the first beta came out I’ve been trying to find out if “real” multitasking is possible — i.e. can you put a program in the background and have it hang on to a network connection indefinitely?

I’m thinking about IM or IRC apps, for example. I’ve compiled an app myself on iOS 4, and without changing a thing it *appeared* to stay running in the background, but for all I know it was just suspended to memory.

The docs say the best you can do is request up to 10 minutes, but in the developer presentation they showed off Skype sitting in the background and then notifying the user that a call was coming in. Does anyone know for sure how this all works?

Comment: I have 0 iOS experience, so this may not be helpful. However, why don't you just have it do something while running in the background to see if it actually is running (for example, update a counter every second)?

Comment: Good idea! I'm going to try that now...

Comment: I just set up a timer to fire every second and ping my web server. Sure enough, the timer stopped firing when the app went into the background, even though when it came back it went right back to the state it was in when it was suspended.

Comment: @plkulak, do you have that link to the docs, you mention on your question? I'm searching for some 'multitasking' framework documentation for os4, but I can't find any resource yet.

Thanks.

Comment: why do you need IM messages in the background when you can't even see them. notifications that messages are available is plenty, then when you do switch back to your IM app it catches up with the new messages, you get what you need, and good battery life, what is the big deal here?

Comment: You need to be a registered Apple dev. Then it's pretty easy to find the docs.

@fuzzy: It's overly complicated. I have to rely on some complicated relay server setup, that while great in theory never really works very well. Beejive always signs me out after about a minute. I had a Nexus One with Google Chat always running in the background and battery life was fine. I don't think it takes much to just leave a connection hanging.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears the answer is no. The API for Skype is a very special case, called the "voip" mode, and requires special behavior, such as marking the socket in use for VoIP.

You can receive alarm notifications in the background (such as time passed). The amount of time you are in the background running state is severely limited by the OS.

Android's background model is complete and in many ways much nicer.

Apple has a guide named "Supporting Multitasking In Your Applications" which you should be able to locate.

Comment: Fully-operational background mode is easier for developers to deal with, but brutal on battery life. That's the design tradeoff Apple has made here. Not to be an Apple apologist, but you can understand the design choice if you think like a user instead of a developer.

Comment: I want it as a user. I want proper IRC and chat applications, and I want developers to be free to do what they need to do to create the applications that I want. Maybe I'm a geeky user, and not typical, but I'm still thinking like a user.

Comment: @pkulak and conversely you want batter life that is only good for a couple of hours for what you want. Real non-developer end users, want a phone that lasts all day and does what they need, they don't care HOW it does it. If it appears to do what you "want" but doesn't do it how you think it should be done, what is the difference.

Comment: why do you need IM messages in the background when you can't even see them. notifications that messages are available is plenty, then when you do switch back to your IM app it catches up with the new messages, you get what you need, and good battery life, what is the big deal here?

Comment: @fuzzy lollipop: My Android phones does just fine receiving messages in the background, and includes a notification system capable of having more than one notification queued at a time.

Comment: @theatrus I never said anything about Android and what it did and didn't do but since you bring it up,the battery life on the N1 ( and most other Android phones ) is atrocious. One of my developer friends is abandoning his N1 because it only lasts about half a day and his 3G lasts a day and a half to two days doing the same things.

Comment: you can create a long running background task... https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Answer (score 8):

Apple's iOS 4 developer docs outline this all very clearly.

When your app is closed or switched away from, it is almost immediately "suspended", meaning the OS freezes the app's state. When the user switches back to your app, your code keeps running just where it kept off. You don't *need* to add any code to your app to do this, just compile it against OS 4.

The above is true in most cases. There are two reasons the "suspended" model may not apply:

1) If the device starts to run low on memory, the OS will start terminating suspended apps that haven't been switched to in a while, without warning. This is why it's in your best interest for your app to remember it's state as well, so if your app is terminated, then re-opened, the user doesn't really notice because it still returns to right where they left off.

2) Your app uses one of the "background" APIs. These are for audio playback, VoIP services, or location services. In this case, your app is allowed to continue running in the background but only has access to those APIs. Additionally, your app can designate certain long-running tasks as "background tasks" that need to be completed before the app is suspended or terminated, like uploading pictures to Flickr or rendering a video, etc.

The "background task" method doesn't cover pinging servers indefinitely, as there is a time limit for the task, after which it will be forcibly halted. Apps that need that sort of functionality are expected to implement push notifications, just as before.

That should clear this up. All in all I think it's a pretty elegant solution to multitasking on a mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 4 applications can either be **running** or **suspended**. The operating system will try to keep as many requested applications as possible in memory, while all other applications are suspended.

Applications that run in the **background** can access features such as navigation, audio, and VOIP (but **NOT** instant messaging). So it looks like you might be out of luck.

-- [PC World Multitasking on Apples iPhone 4](http://www.pcworld.com/article/198296/multitasking_on_apples_iphone_4_how_does_it_work.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for apps to request background time. Read the docs. I would say it iOS is "controlled multitasking".

Answer (score 1):

You can create a long running background task, I believe these can include networking features.  Just have to set the background task flag on the work block.

https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

the OS can limit exactly how much time you get though...  it will tell you when your time is up giving you a chance to cleanup nicely.

Comment: It's important that you do as much cleanup as possible *before* you move into the background, though. If the phone is running low on memory and has to kill your app, you don't get any warning at all, you just get killed.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 4 has "real" multitasking to some extend. There are two things to consider:

- The UI event loop is single tasking. So only the front app executes on the UI event loop. Not a big deal: detach your main code form the UI event loop (maybe you need to redesign your app).
- The OS "may" terminate your app if some criteria are met (e.g. low memory).

Currently one of these criteria is that execution time is limited to 10 minutes (real time not cpu time). However I expect this to change and see better criteria for background app termination (I hope to).

Apart from this you can have [timers (event loops) in background](http://www.christian-fries.de/blog/files/20010-06-iOSMultitaksing.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is no real multitasking in iOS 4.2 even. because apps will only be allowed to finish the task related to states..for small interval of time and then it will be in suspended state.. If you will set background task for long interval of time then... it will behave unexpectedly like no method will be called when you will try to run the app from anywhere..

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [this blog post](http://blog.rlove.org/2010/04/iphone-os-4-and-multitasking.html) that outlines how "multitasking" works in systems such as iPhone OS 4 and Android.

Comment: Note that Android does not have the same limits on services as iOS. It is quite possible to have a network connected service running continuously in the background, unlike iOS. The service can be started and stopped by the application (or its self), and the service can launch intents (much more flexible than the iOS counterpart). The notifications mentioned are named "broadcasts" in Android, and do not require a running service.

Answer (score 0):

in fact u can do this, although it's not allowed by Apple. u gotta set up a toolchain in ur mac and use some unofficial SDK...

check http://code.google.com/p/iphone-backgrounder/ for more information

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Push Notifications framework for the feature set you are creating!