# Make a call from iPhone application without quitting

Tags: iphone, call, multitasking

Is it possible to make a call from application with out quitting application in iOS 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to have your application *remember its state*. That way it can be resumed when launched again. Even with the new *multitasking* your suspended apps may be forcibly quit if the device needs more memory.

Apple has a guide named "Supporting Multitasking In Your Applications" which you should be able to locate.

Related SO: [Does iOS 4 make “Real Multitasking” available to 3rd party developers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003245/ddg#3003369)

However, you may not replicate core OS functionality so this is the only way to get what you want.