# Return the user to my application after making a phone call

Tags: ios, phone-call

I want the user to be able to call a phone number form within my app. Is it possible for the user to be returned straight back to the application after finishing the call?

Comment: This gave an awesome app idea. hahah.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a call from iPhone application without quitting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957043/make-a-call-from-iphone-application-without-quitting)

Comment: Please ask two separate questions separately.

Comment: See also: [How do I test if iOS device has telephone capabilities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736110/how-do-i-test-if-ios-device-has-telephone-capabilities)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1: I guess that this is the default behavior, isn't it?

2: you can check if the device can open the `tel://` protocol:

```
BOOL canCall = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but this can be done using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://111222333"]];
```

I believe this can be done for iOS >= 5.0.

The behaviour of `telprompt://` is slightly different than `tel://`.

Answer (score 0):

**1**

It depends how you initiate the call.

You can chose between:

- Present a pop-up in which the user has to approve the call. Your app will be launched afterwards again.
- Directly call, without showing a pop-up first. Your app wont be launched after the call.

for how to implement both ways, please read this question: [iOS 4.2 - Return to app after phone call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028329/ios-4-2-return-to-app-after-phone-call)

**2**

Check if the device can open `tel:` URLs with the following code:

```
BOOL isPhone = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:123456789"]];
```

Comment: Aren't you missing the `//`after `tel:`? Also, I wouldn't name it `isPhone` - maybe a future iPad or jailbroken iPods can call...

Comment: @Jenox according to [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007893-SW1), you are not using `//` after `tel:`

Comment: @Jenox I am using it in my apps without, works perfectly for me …